# Upload Video and Captions with Youtube API 3.0?

Tags: api, video, youtube, captions

i'm trying to upload my new youtube's video associated to my caption's file (.srt).
I see that Youtube API 2.0 is now deprecated so i would do that with 3.0.

But, i didn't see anything to upload my captions in 3.0.

I would like to upload my video with some captions file associated to it.
Any idea ?

I'm using PHP.